# Defining a list of files using Tkinter to use for analysis. Having a hard time accessing the variables globally. (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I hope all is well. Fairly new to programming, so please bear with me.

I am working on a GUI using tkinter that would prompt me to select a set of files that would be used to perform some analysis. I wish to store these files in a list that I can reference later. There are two required files, a DBC file and an ASC file. What I am having issues with is being able to reference the file(s) outside of the functions I have defined. I have tried defining it as a global variable (which I have read is not advisable as it can lead to problems down the road). I get an error saying dbfiles or ascfiles is not defined when just trying to print. Below is what I have written so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x700")

def dbbutton():
    dbfiles = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Select .DBC File(s)')
    dbfiles = root.tk.splitlist(dbfiles)
    for file1 in dbfiles:
        L1.insert(tk.END, file1)
    return dbfiles


def ascbutton():
    ascfiles = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Select .ASC File(s)')
    ascfiles = root.tk.splitlist(ascfiles)
    for file2 in ascfiles:
        L2.insert(tk.END, file2)
    return ascfiles


b1 = tk.Button (root, text= "Select Database File(s)", command = dbbutton)
b1.pack()
L1 = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode = "multiple", height = 10, width = 80)
L1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button (root, text = "Select ASC File(s)", command = ascbutton)
b2.pack()
L2 = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode = "multiple", height = 10, width = 80 )
L2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What is the most effective way for me to reference these files outside of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Create the file list outside the function and then append to it inside the function:

```
ascfile_list = []   # Create list to hold filenames
def ascbutton():
    filename_list = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Select .ASC File(s)')
    for filename in filename_list:
        L2.insert(tk.END, filename)
        ascfile_list.append(filename)  # Append filename to list
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick. I learned this trick a couple of weeks ago, totally forgot about. I really appreciate the help.